# Add to gCal button for website

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm looking for a way to make a button appear on my website so that users can automatically add events to their google calendar, similar to what is done by http://www.addthisevent.com/ (currently what I'm using).

I've looked online so far, but I can only find a manual way of doing it by adding it to my calendar and generating code from that. However I'd like to do it automatically with PHP.

My reasoning for not wanting to continue is to give myself control over all of the resources loading on the website.

EDIT: I'm looking for a link which users can click and a new tab will open with the add calendar appointment open and pre-filled (as is done by *addthisevent*).
The solution should be PHP only and accept all of the variables required for google calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code maybe can helps:

Google Calendar:

```
<?php
function generate_calendar_button($name, $description, DateTime $start, DateTime $end, $location, $mysite_url, $mysite_name) {
   $url = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE';
   $parts = array();
   $parts['text'] = urlencode($name);
   $parts['details'] = urlencode($description);
   $parts['dates'] = urlencode($start->format("Ymd\THis\Z")) . "/" . urlencode($end->format("Ymd\THis\Z"));
   $parts['location'] = urlencode($location);
   $parts['sprop'] = urlencode($mysite_url);
   $full_link = $url;
   foreach ($parts as $key => $value) {
      $full_link .= "&" . $key . "=" . $value;
   }
   $full_link .= "&sprop=name:" . urlencode($mysite_name);
   return '<a href="' . $full_link . '" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.google.com/calendar/images/ext/gc_button1.gif" border=0></a>';
}

print generate_calendar_button(
    "Boulevard Summer Show",
    "Starting Friday 15th June, the Boulevard Summer Show 2012 features new sets and musical numbers led by the legendary Betty Legs Diamond, performing alongside established favourites and some rather fetching new faces, all held together by the incomparable Miss Rory.",
    new DateTime("2012-07-15 8:00 GMT"),
    new DateTime("2012-07-15 10:00 GMT"),
    "123 Example Lane, Exampleville",
    "http://www.northernpink.co.uk/",
    "Northern Pink"
);

?>
```

Apple iCal:

```
<?php // Add a custom button after the event export options that display after the event content


$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . "@yourhost.test
DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. gmdate('His') . "Z
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T035959Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";

//set correct content-type-header
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=calendar.ics');
echo $ical;
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it when I get a minute

Comment: It worked? I think it's all working :)

Comment: Please let me know it!

Comment: For the iCal, is a new page required? Asking because it changes the header